# How can I use wildcards to search for a last name in AD?

Tags: vbscript, active-directory, ldap

```
"<LDAP://DC=top,DC=example,DC=com>;(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sn=%lastname%));sAMAccountName,sn,givenName,distinguishedname,userAccountControl,cn"
```

Above is a snippet of my query that I will send to AD. When I type an EXACT last name, it works without issues. However when I enter a partial last name, I get no results.

Can anyone please tell me how to perform a search on a partial name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%` is not a valid wildcard in [LDAP filters](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx), and you also can't use environment variables (`%variable%`) in VBScript LDAP queries. A filter with a partial value can be defined like this:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sn=*something*))
```

If you want to use a variable in a filter you have to use string concatenation:

```
"(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sn=" & variable & "))"
```